# Import data in Sparksee in batch mode

Tags: graph-databases

Is there a utility for batch import of data in Sparksee graph database? I am looking something [BatchInserter](http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.3/org/neo4j/unsafe/batchinsert/BatchInserter.html) interface in Neo4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a scripting option for Sparksee that enables you to batch load CSV files.  The documentation can be found [here](http://www.sparsity-technologies.com/UserManual/Scripting.html).

I have personally never used the scripting feature.  I stumbled upon this feature in the [Sparksee Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sparksee/I1aLMXR_0Gk).